# jQuery if any of an element's parents' href begins with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm trying to achieve is a way to check if any of an element's parents' href begin with something. Here's how far I've come:

```
$('.element').click(function(e){
    if($(this).is('[href^="X"')){
        // How to check if the clicked element's href begins with X
    }
});
```

But this is not what I want. I wanna check if any of the element's parents have a href beginning with something.

Any ideas?

Gustaf

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't think that is required in order to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest, given that nesting an `<a>` element is invalid so that there can be only one ancestor `<a>` element (or no ancestor `<a>` elements, obviously):

```
$('.element').click(function(e){
    // here we use a terribly-, but meaningfully-, named variable
    // to hold the Boolean result of the assessment;
    // the assessment looks from the clicked element up through
    // the ancestors for the first <a> element matching the
    // attribute-starts-with selector ([href^=x])
    // this will return either 1 or 0 elements.
    // we check the length; if it's equal to 1 then the ancestor
    // has an href starting with x, if it's 0 then there is either
    // no ancestor <a> element or no ancestor <a> element with a
    // href matching the attribute-starts-with selector:
    var ancestorAnchorStartsWithX = $(this).closest('a[href^=x]').length === 1;
});
```

It's worth noting, as [@A. Wolff did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547520/jquery-if-any-of-an-elements-parents-href-begins-with#comment49167545_30547551), in the comments below, that:

> …`closest()` [checks the] element itself too.

Which means that if the clicked element itself matches the selector supplied to closest (and is therefore an `<a>` element with an `href` beginning with `x`) then the assessment will return true, even though it's not an ancestor element. I considered this a feature – while writing out the selector – but I forgot to detail that in the answer itself.

If this is considered a bug, then an option using `parents('a[href^=x]')` in place of `closest('a[href^=x]')` will be more appropriate to your use-case.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Elegant solution, will mark as solution asap! Cheers

Comment: As a side note, `closest()` check for element itself too. It would be more relevant to use `parents()` instead even i guess it doesn't really matter in OP specific use case

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :) And, @A.Wolff, I hadn't mentioned that but I assumed that would be a feature (rather than a bug) in this case, in the event that click events might propagate to that ancestor `<a>` element. But yes: I should have mentioned that, having thought of it.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thx for fixing my bad english ;) Not a joke, i really appreciate it

Comment: @A.Wolff: I'm English, those thanks will likely always inspire a certain amount of guilt, however sincere you may be ;) but you're welcome! Though it's less about my desire to help (and certainly no desire to embarrass) but more about the consequences of having studied English Literature at university. Some things became hard-wired... :) Oh, and genuinely, your bad English is infinitely (literally *infinitely*) better than my best attempt at any non-English language.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".element").click(function(e) {
  var res = $(this).parents("[href^=X]").is("*");
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<a href="Xabc123">
  <div class="element">click</div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
$('.element').click(function(e){
      var $parents=$(this).parents();
      var matches=$parents.filter('[href^="x"]');
      if(matches.length){
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: You should check for: `$(this).parents('[href^="x"]').length`

Comment: @A.Wolff what's the difference?

Comment: In you case (after fixing typo) `var matches=$parents.filter('[href^="x"]');`, `matches` would always be truthly

Comment: Specifically because a jQuery object - even if it contains no found-elements - is always truthy, since an object is always returned.

Comment: I missed that we were just checking for existence.  I've fixed answer.